# function returns much larger increase in value than expected

Tags: javascript

I am currently making a web game, as a university project. It is basically a modern tamagochi game using JS that involves manipulating the pet's statistics (health, happiness, sleep, etc.) by clicking buttons. I can reduce the statistics just fine. However, the problem comes when I try to increase them. For example, when I try to increase the SLEEP statistic by 3, it ends up going all the way to 100 (the SLEEP value was 48 when I clicked the button).

```
const statButtons = document.querySelector(".stats-buttons")
const health = document.getElementById("health")
const energy = document.getElementById("rest")

const restButton = document.getElementById("restButton")
const hungerButton = document.getElementById("hungerButton") 
const baseSleepIncrease = 3

function dropStat(stat, value) {
  let currentPercent = stat.ariaValueNow
  if (currentPercent > 0) {
    stat.style.width = `${currentPercent-value}%`
    stat.ariaValueNow = currentPercent - value
  }


}

function increaseStat(stat, value) {
  let currentPercent = stat.ariaValueNow;
  if ((currentPercent + value) <= 100) {
    stat.ariaValueNow = currentPercent + value
  }

  else {
    stat.ariaValueNow = 100
    
  }

  stat.style.width = `${stat.ariaValueNow}`


}

function getRandomInRange(min,max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max-min)) + max
}

function getSleep() {
  const currentEnergyValue = rest.ariaValueNow
  // const sleepQuality = getRandomInRange(0.7,1) * (health.ariaValueNow/100)  
  const sleepValue = baseSleepIncrease

  increaseStat(rest,sleepvalue)
  increaseStat(health, (baseHealthIncrease * sleepQuality))
  alert(`current value of sleep:${sleepValue}`)
}


setInterval(()=> {
  dropStat(health,idleHealthDropOff)
  dropStat(energy,idleRestDropOff)
},1000)


$("#restButton").click(()=> {
  getSleep()
})
```

Any help would be appreciated